# Django JOIN on nested model Foreign key with look up field

Tags: mysql, django, serialization, django-rest-framework, foreign-keys

I'm using **2 models** in **Django Rest Framework**.

```
class Questions(models.Model):
    question = models.TextField()
    answer = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Categories, related_name="cat_questions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)


class QuestionnaireResult(models.Model):
    patient_info = models.ForeignKey(PatientInfo, related_name="+", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    questions = models.ForeignKey(Questions, related_name="result_questions", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    answer_given = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

having **serializers** for both:

```
class QuestionnaireResultSerailizer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = QuestionnaireResult
        fields = '__all__'


class QuestionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    result_questions = QuestionnaireResultSerailizer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Questions
        fields ='__all__'
```

**views:**

```
class QuestionsViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Questions.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionsSerializer


class QuestionnaireResultViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = QuestionnaireResult.objects.all()
    serializer_class = QuestionnaireResultSerializer
    filter_backends = (filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ['patient_info']
```

Using URL - `http://localhost:9000/api/questions/1`, It gives result based on **question_id = 1** and **result_questions** contains only those nested records which have **questions id == 1**. That is correct.

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "result_questions": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "answer_given": "no",
            "timestamp": "2017-10-01T12:28:19.770454Z",
            "patient_info": 1,
            "questions": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "answer_given": "no",
            "timestamp": "2017-10-01T13:13:19.658930Z",
            "patient_info": 2,
            "questions": 1
        }
    ],
    "question": "digestive ques 1",
    "answer": "yes",
    "timestamp": "2017-09-30T17:04:59.143857Z",
    "categories": 1
}
```

But above **nested json (result_questions)** returns **all patient_info** which has **questions id == 1** but I want to **add one more filter(patient_info)** on it. I want only those **patient_info** which I want to retrieve by passing as **look up field**.

What I want is that. Assume, I use this url `http://localhost:9000/api/questions/1?patient_info=1`

It returns response having **question_id == 1 and patient_info ==1.** Therefore, response should be like:

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "result_questions": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "answer_given": "no",
            "timestamp": "2017-10-01T12:28:19.770454Z",
            "patient_info": 1,
            "questions": 1
        }
    ],
    "question": "digestive ques 1",
    "answer": "yes",
    "timestamp": "2017-09-30T17:04:59.143857Z",
    "categories": 1
}
```

Comment: Post your view as well, please

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov Posted view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try [serializermethodfield](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#serializermethodfield)

```
class QuestionsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    result_questions = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Questions
        fields ='__all__'

    def get_result_questions(self, obj):
        qs = obj.result_questions.all()
        request = self.context.get('request')
        patient_info = request.GET.get('patient_info')
        if patient_info:
            qs = qs.filter(patient_info=patient_info)
        return QuestionnaireResultSerailizer(qs, many=True).data
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Can you help me to find interactive tutorial to learn django rest framework ?

Comment: glad to help you. i was start to learn drf  by [django-angularjs-tutorial](https://thinkster.io/django-angularjs-tutorial)

Comment: There is an issue. If I use `serializers.SerializerMethodField()`. I can't do `POST` request. It throws error - `"errors": "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GET'"`

Comment: for post action you need to override `create` method if use `SerializerMethodField`

Comment: or try to understand the answer of @neverwalkaloner and fix errors

Answer (score 1):

In view try to use `prefetch_related` inside `get_object` method:

```
def get_object(self, pk):
    try:
        return Questions.objects.prefetch_related(Prefetch('result_questions',  
            queryset=QuestionnaireResult.objects.filter(id=self.request.GET.get('patient_info')))).get(pk=pk)
    except Questions.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404
```

Comment: It throw - `get_object() takes exactly 2 arguments (1 given)`